# Auto Patcher (Efficient Auto Updater)

Tags: c#, .net, auto-update, patch

I want an auto updater that detect modified files (by comparing files on the client-side and a server) and only download modified files. I also want it to give me its status lively (To show it on a process bar or something)

The scenario is that there's about one thousand clients in a network, that use same application. If a new version of the application is available, they all have to get the new version. But, the bandwidth is limited, so it's not very efficient to give them a **full installer** each time. (Which we do currently)

I searched around a little, and I found [IcePatch2](http://www.zeroc.com/icepatch2/index.html). It do the exact thing I want: Getting the newest files from server when the patcher is run. But the problem is that clients wrote in **C#**, and I can't use IcePatch2 **inside** my application. (I have to run it as a separate process, or write a COM or something to interact with the IcePatch2Client)

So far, the best solution I found is to get [*.NET Application Updater Component*](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx) and customize it to fit my needs. But I prefer a solution that dose not require me to maintain another application.

Any idea?

Comment: Fully running an updater inside your application doesn't work well. Windows locks the files of running programs so they can't be replaced. So you either need an outside patcher or a launcher which gets(almost) never patched.

Answer (score 3):

We use [wyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/).

It produces binary delta patches - even better than file-level. It also has a client auto-update component too: [wyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wyupdate/).

Answer (score 2):

We use [AppLifeUpdate](http://www.kineticjump.com/update/default.aspx).  You can create update packages that contain only the chnaged files.  I'm not sure if it does binary deltas though.  It is a .NET component and can optionally use a service that you install to do elevated installer updates (only really needed for changes affecting all users on a system).