# Cross Platform Auto Updater

Tags: qt, qt4, auto-update

I am using Qt in order to build a cross platform GUI app (Windows and Mac). I want to be able to update the app efficiently and automatically whenever there is a new patch available.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323839/auto-patcher-efficient-auto-updater) post which got me to take a look at [WyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/). It looks great and probably what I may end up using for the Windows version but what about Mac? What are some alternatives available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mac the best choice is [`Sparkle`](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) used by WebKit, Adium, Cyberduck and more. Its only for Mac but I guess native look matters on Mac a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I've just started developing a Qt-based autoupdater called [Fervor](https://github.com/pypt/fervor) for my own needs. You can try it out, contributions are more than welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with WyBuild so cannot comment. Sparkle is a fine choice but the poster preferred a single app for both platforms. [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) contains an autoupdater written in Qt that can be used independently  (disclaimer, I am the original BitRock developer). It is a commercial app, but we have free licenses for open source projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Updatenode](http://www.updatenode.com/main) which seems to provide a real Qt cross-platform solution.

It comes with a prebuilt client for Windows, Mac and Linux. The online service lets you manage updates very easy and are able to see good charts of your application usage.

Comment: This might be a nice GPL licensed QT client, but you are forced to use the Updatenode API for commerical products. It's only free for open-source products. See https://www.updatenode.com/main#pricing

Answer (score 1):

And here another one of the possibilities:

Using the [Qt Installer Framework](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework): It provides installers for Windows/Linux/Mac with an build-in updater. If you need an example - The MaintenanceTool of your Qt-Installation uses the framework.

To get an auto-updater from it, all you need to do is:

- Create an online installer (Just check the documentation, it's not that hard)
- Use the maintenancetool in your application to check for updates.

  - This cane be done using my [QtAutoUpdater](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtAutoUpdater). Go there for more information about the whole process
  - If new updates are available, the maintenancetool can be started in updater mode to install the update
- Update the online repository - and your update is out.

Advantages:

- Installer and updater in 1 tool - this means less work for you
- Easy to use (with or without the QtAutoUpdater library)
- Cross-Platform for all desktop platforms supported by Qt
- The installer itself is a Qt original

Disadvantages:

- No "native" installers (i.e. no `.msi` on windows or `.deb` on ubuntu)
- Must be used together - if you want to use the update feature, you have to use the framework as installer

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but for Linux you can use the built in package manager. For example, `apt-get`, `yum`, `pacman`, or what have you.